# Using AdMob with Games that use Open GLES

Tags: android, platformer

Can anyone help me integrating Admob to my game. I've used the badlogic framework by MarioZencher ... and My game is like the SuperJumper. I am unable to use AdMob after a lot of my attempts. I am new to android dev...please help me..I went thru a number of tutorials but not getting adds displayed ...

I did the following...

1. get the libraries and placed them properly
2. My main.xml looks like this

   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:text="@string/hello"
   />

1. My Activity class onCreate method:

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   ```
   RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
   adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a1518637fe542a2");
   AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
   request.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
   request.addTestDevice("D77E32324019F80A2CECEAAAAAAAAA");    
   adView.loadAd(request);
         layout.addView(glView);
         RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams =
                 new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
         adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
         adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
         layout.addView(adView, adParams);
         setContentView(layout);




   requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
   getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
   glView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
   glView.setRenderer(this);
   //setContentView(glView);

   glGraphics = new GLGraphics(glView);
   fileIO = new AndroidFileIO(getAssets());
   audio = new AndroidAudio(this);
   input = new AndroidInput(this, glView, 1, 1);
   PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
   wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "GLGame");
   ```

   }
2. My Manifest file looks like this ....

```
    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|smallestScreenSize"/>

</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
```

When I first decided to use the XML for admob purpose ..it showed no changes..it even didn't log the device id in Logcat...

Later when I wrote code in the Main Activity class.. and run ...
Application crashed ... with 7 errors evry time ...

The android:configChanges value of the com.google.ads.AdActivity must include screenLayout.

The android:configChanges value of the com.google.ads.AdActivity must include uiMode.

The android:configChanges value of the com.google.ads.AdActivity must include screenSize.

The android:configChanges value of the com.google.ads.AdActivity must include smallestScreenSize.

You must have AdActivity declared in AndroidManifest.xml with configChanges.

You must have INTERNET and ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permissions in AndroidManifest.xml.

Please help me by telling what wrong is there with the code?
Can I write code only in xml files without changing the Activity class ...
I will be very grateful to anyone providing support.

Comment: Have you tried making the changes which the error messages indicate are necessary to your manifest file?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the admob activity to your android manifest.. The following question has a good example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214308/android-admob-how-to-declare-adactivity-in-manifest

```
        <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

Comment: Yes.. it's already added....

Comment: You're missing screenLayout|uiMode, and you also need to add: INTERNET and access NETWORK STATE

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>